# fanotify: monitor one specific folder - not the whole filesystem

Tags: c, linux, fanotify

I used the [example](http://www.xypron.de/projects/fanotify-manpages/man7/fanotify.7.html) of the fanotify manpage to get all paths, where an file-access occured. But i only want the file-access monitored from one specific folder e.g. /tmp/myfolder.

For that i add my specific folder "/tmp/myfolder":

```
fanotify_mark(fd,
          FAN_MARK_ADD | FAN_MARK_MOUNT,
          event_mask,
          AT_FDCWD,
          "/tmp/myfolder")))
```

Event mask:

```
    static uint64_t event_mask = (FAN_OPEN |
                              FAN_EVENT_ON_CHILD);
```

Even i play with FAN_ONDIR for get only the file-accesses from this special directory, i ever get all filehandles from the whole filesystem. I start my compiled program with sudo ./program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing FAN_MARK_MOUNT.  That may be telling it to give you all events for the mounted filesystem containing the path.